# FOP2 installed successfully but not listing all or atleast 15 extensions

Tags: php

I am new to **FOP2**.
I have `freepbx version 12.0.1`. `FOP2 manager` version is 1.0 and `FOP2` version 2+. PHP version 5.3.3.
I have installed `FOP2` in my centos and the GUI working fine. I have created 18 exensions in `freepbx`.
I have created one user "100",Group "Test" and allocated all extensiosns under that group from FOP2 admin portal.When i am login as "100" user then I can only see **13 extensions** (not all of them).
Also as i have seen that "FOP2 - Version 2.28 - Lite Version - Limited to 15 extensions" so it should be display 15 extensions.

Can anybody know why I am not getting 15 extensions?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is fairly old, but I may as well pick it upp.
It's actually 15 buttons. In fop2/admin you have to disable unwanted buttons, such as call parking, trunk, or queue that might be enabled.